# TestNG Re run test on failure, not running BeforeClass AfterClass methods

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, annotations, testng

I implemented logic that re runs a failed TestNG test class from the following link:

https://martinholladay.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/webdriver-2-0-automatically-retry-failed-tests/

Unfortunately, it runs the method with the "Test" annotation, and not running the BeforeClass (@BeforeClass) and AfterClass (@AfterClass) methods. I tried looking into setDependsOnMethods and getDependsOnMethods methods of ITestAnnotations to no avail.

Does anybody know how to get the listener class to run BeforeClass and AfterClass methods as well?

```
public class RetryListener implements IAnnotationTransformer {
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass,
            Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
        IRetryAnalyzer retry = annotation.getRetryAnalyzer();
        if (retry == null) {
            annotation.setRetryAnalyzer(Retry.class);
        }
    }
}

//The test begins here....

@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
@Parameters("Environment")
public void BeforeClass(String sEnv) throws Exception {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("www.google.com");

}

@Test
public void TestMethod() {
    //Some test...
}

@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void AfterClass() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

Comment: Can you copy the relevant code into your question?

Comment: @jsmith Yes I have been facing similar issue, `RetryListener ` does not run whole test class it just runs the test which failed. So it won't execute any thing except @Test. To run entire test class again you have to use something else for e.g. you can testng-failed.xml from testng-report directory. Write some code to run the testng-failed.xml when you get any failure. But it will always run at end of execution.

Answer (score 0):

TestNG invokes only failed `@Test` methods. You can see implementation here https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/internal/Invoker.java#L1408

So no, you can't invoke `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` in RetryListener again.